# How did the infected soldier rise from the dead in Tomb Raider (2018)?

Tags: lara-croft-tomb-raider, tomb-raider-2018

I'm so eager to know how the dead infected soldier in the *Tomb Raider* (2018) film rose from the dead to attack Richard Croft..?

He was infected, started to turn into some ghoul and eventually was already losing his life when he got shot, that did him really, but then several minutes later he somehow rises from the dead, how?

Comment: So I feel I should preface by saying that they were really trying to put a "spin of science" on the entire situation. The queen had a disease that she was immune to and all the other people were not. So, whatever the reason it should be logical and possible. That said, we don't know for sure. They don't explain more than we see. We need more information (book or sequel) to know why... However, who says he was really dead when he laid there for those few minutes? Maybe he was in a sort of catatonic state as the infection took hold...

Comment: @Odin1806 He was shot and was lying unconscious for several minutes, how doesn't that make him surely dead? Watching prior how rapidly the disease was spreading we can assume he wasn't a live body anymore.

Comment: ...cause being unconscious is not the same thing as being dead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confusing the soldier that was initially infected to the one that rises from the "dead" to attack Richard. The soldier that was initially infected is this guy who touched Himiko directly with his bare skin. Note you can see the third Trinity soldier in the background of this image:

[image: Trinity soldier is infected]

However, the Trinity soldier that rises from the "dead" to attack Richard is actually this guy.

[image: Trinity soldier rises from the "dead" to attack Richard]

As you can see he is a completely different guy, one who was not actually infected when he "died". He "dies" when he is shot by the aforementioned infected soldier, though as you can see he is wearing a bulletproof vest so he presumably just got knocked unconscious.

Given this it actually remains unclear how this soldier got infected. He might not actually have been infected but given his actions and that Richard then apparently gets infected after the fight I would say he must have been.